# Chromium message : google api keys are missing and cannot sign in to chromium

Tags: apt, google-chrome, chromium

I installed Chromium on my Ubuntu 12.04 using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Now whenever I run it I get the message

> google api keys are missing
>   some functionality of chromium will be disabled

and I cannot sign into my google account to get all my bookmarks.

If I press learn more... it takes me to a page where it asks me to subscribe to chromium dev channel, search for my api key and provide keys at build time or run time. But I don't know how to do that... please help...

Comment: The ppa clearly states "NOTE: Some Chromium features, including Sync, require an API key, which is not included with the packages below." So what you are seeing is expected. The ppa owner, @saiarcot895, has given a link to getting what is required.

Comment: Here are the instructions: https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-dev/+index?field.series_filter=